# I'm able to run the Gwt application through eclipse, but once i created a war file and deploying into tomcat server not able to access the gw

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, internet-explorer-11, war

I'm able to run the Gwt application through eclipse, but once i created a war file and deploying into tomcat server not able to access the gwt application.

I have created GWT project in eclipse and now i'm able to access the gwt application through IE11 and Chrome(which connects to a server and retrieves data).

I have created war file using ANT build and after deploying war in tomcat9.0.14, when I try to access the application, i'm getting the following error in tomcat logs.

Url:http://servername:8080/migrationService/Migration.html

## ==========================
Unable to sign off of spurce server. 404  <!doctype html>HTTP Status 404 – Not Foundh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

**Type** Status Report

**Message** /XXXXMigration/XXXXXmigration/migrateService

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.14

can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

The server is reporting a 404 [HTTP Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) which means "page not found".  In other words, you have misconfigured the server. It could be that the service is not installed, or is not mapped to `/migrationService` or the service is unable to find or serve the `Migration.html` page.

It's not a GWT, Chrome or IE11 problem. It's a server configuration problem.